# Async way of implementing search query in Elastic Search Nest Client .NET

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

I have implemented a Search Query through NEST client and was able to get the records. The code is as follows.

```
 var response = clientProvider.Client.Search<ProjectModel>(s => s
                   .Index("project_index")
                   .Type("projects")
                   .Source(so => so.Excludes(f => f.Field(x => x.FileInfo.FileBase64Data)))
                   .Size(100)
                   .Query(q => q
                       .Bool(b => b
                           .Should(
                               m => m.QueryString(qs => qs
                                    .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                    .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))
                                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)

                                    ),
                               m => m.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                                    .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                    .Type(Nest.TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                                    .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))

                                    )
                                  )
                            )
                         )
                           .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score))
                         );
```

And I am mapping the response to my Project Model as follows.

```
 var project = response.Hits.Select(h =>
                {
                    h.Source._id = h.Id;
                    h.Source.Score = h.Score;
                    return h.Source;
                }).ToList();
```

When I am trying to implement the same Search in Async way that is

```
 var response = clientProvider.Client.SearchAsync<ProjectModel>(s => s
                   .Index("project_index")
                   .Type("projects")
                   .Source(so => so.Excludes(f => f.Field(x => x.FileInfo.FileBase64Data)))
                   .Size(100)
                   .Query(q => q
                       .Bool(b => b
                           .Should(
                               m => m.QueryString(qs => qs
                                    .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                    .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))
                                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)

                                    ),
                               m => m.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                                    .Query(searchOptions.SearchTerm)
                                    .Type(Nest.TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                                    .Fields(ff => ff.Fields(fields))

                                    )
                                  )
                            )
                         )
                           .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score))
                         );
```

I am not getting any errors while executing it. But I am not able to get the `response.Hits` objects to map it back to my original Project Model. 
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SearchAsync<T>()`, `response` is `Task<ISearchResponse<T>>`, so you probably want to [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) it

Answer (score 0):

Map all documents, found in `products` index, onto `ProductDto` type:

```cs
var result = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ProductDto>(x => x.Index("products").MatchAll());
var documents = result.Documents;
```